# Add generated sources to classpath

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I use [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin). It generate my classes in the correct directory, but on Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2), the folder is not automaticaly added to the classpath.

Here is my plugin config :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <generatePackage>foo.bar.pojo</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is it possible with maven-jaxb2-plugin to define the genearted directory as source folder ? If yes, how ?

Eclipse shows me an error in the `pom.xml` on `<execution>` :

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

Comment: Try refreshing the project with Alt+F5. It should work OOTB, you don't even need `addCompileSourceRoot`.

Comment: @lexicore Already did but the folderis not added to the classpath :(

Comment: Does `mvn clean install` work? Do you get generated classes compiled?

Comment: @lexicore Yes it works. I have the Java files in the correct folder. But it's not added to the build path

Comment: @lexicore Switch to version 0.12.1 fixed the problem

Comment: Pretty strange, nothing related was changed in 0.13.1. Please file an issue.

Comment: You say *"But it's not added to the build path"* - also not in normal `mvn clean install` build in the command line?

Comment: @lexicore Issue opened : https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/109
And no the mvn clean install in version 0.13.1 do not add the folder to the build path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix my problem, I had to change the version of the plugin.

From :

```
<version>0.13.1</version>
```

To :

```
<version>0.12.1</version>
```